# How to nest a forEach in a forEach to get sum for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

It gives me the items in the array but I am not sure how to total the items together

```
const numArrays = [
    [100, 5, 23],
    [15, 21, 72, 9],
    [45, 66],
    [7, 81, 90]
];
total = [];
    numArrays.forEach(function(n){
      total += n;
    });

    console.log('Exercise 15 Result: ', total);
```

/*
Exercise 15:

- Given the above numArrays array, use nested forEach methods to sum up all the numbers contained within numArrays and assign to a variable named total.
- Hint: Be sure to declare and initialize the total variable before the iterations.
  */

Comment: What language is the code written in? Please [edit] your question to add it as a tag.

Comment: Thank you, I did update my tag and language

Answer (score 1):

```
const numArrays = [
    [100, 5, 23],
    [15, 21, 72, 9],
    [45, 66],
    [7, 81, 90]
];
let total = 0;

numArrays.forEach((parent) => {
    parent.forEach((child) => {
        total += child;
    });
});
```

Comment: THANK YOU. I knew it had to be nested but wasnt sure how to go about it!

Answer (score 1):

I can sum up all the numbers contained within numArrays by nested forEach method.
It works.

```
const numArrays = [
    [100, 5, 23],
    [15, 21, 72, 9],
    [45, 66],
    [7, 81, 90]
];

total = 0;

numArrays.forEach(function(n){
    n.forEach(function(value) {
        total += value;
    })
});

console.log('Exercise 15 Result: ', total);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what reduce method is for.
cur is the current value of the iteration - 100, 5, 23. Accum is the previous tally. which we start with 0.
Each time you return a value in the function - accum gets updated.

```
numArrays.reduce((accum1, cur1) => (
  accum1 + cur1.reduce((accum2, cur2) => (
    accum2 + cur2
  ), 0)
), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use reduce

```
numArrays.reduce((acc, arr) => acc + arr.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue), 0);
```